# php simple DOM parser

Tags: php, html, dom, simpledom

ok so i have been battling with this for a while now so maybe someone can help me.

Im trying to get the email link from this HTML:

```
<div id="field_11" class="fieldRow span12 lastFieldRow">
  <span class="caption">E-mail</span>
  <span class="output">
   <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
     document.write('<a hr'+'ef="mai'+'lto'+':'+
      '%40;%67;%6d;%61;%69;%6c;<\/a>');
    //-->
   </script>
   <a href="mailto:%40%67%6d%61%69%6c">@mail</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Im trying to get the '@mail' part of the html code, after the a href="mailto:..." part. NOT the document.write() part but the last tag in the code.

for some reason when ever i try to get the children of the tag span with the output class it thinks it only has 1 child which is the script tag but i just can't seem to grab the email plain text.

So far what i have:

```
 $target_url = "some_web_site";
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load_file($target_url);

foreach($html->find('span[class=output]') as $d){ 
    echo $d->children(1)->plaintext . "<br />";
 }
```

any help?

Comment: Your code should work, what's the output of it (or the error message) ?

Comment: it prints out a bunch of these errors: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/webcrawler/index.php on line 224

Comment: Sounds like your `load_file()` isn't loading right. Can you try removing the 2nd and 3rd lines (both beginning with `$html`, and replace with `$html = file_get_html($target_url);`?

Comment: @LaughDonor  - tried your approach, still got those errors.

Comment: Well, the main reason you're having this problem is `$html->find('span[class=output]')` is returning `null`. You need to check to make sure your selectors are correct. Maybe using `span.output` instead?

Comment: gives me the same error with 'span.output'. could this be the website preventing me or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with just DOM+Xpath, too.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
//$dom->loadHtmlFile($htmlFile);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate(
    'string(//span[@class="output"]//a[starts-with(@href, "mailto:")])'
  )
);
```

Output: https://eval.in/148063

```
string(5) "@mail"
```

The Xpath selects all `span` elements with the `class` attribute "output"

`//span[@class="output"]`

Then it looks for `a` elements where the `href` attribute starts with "mailto:"

`//span[@class="output"]//a[starts-with(@href, "mailto:")]`

The result of this is a list of `a` element nodes (with the example content a single node). The `string()` function casts the first node into a string if the node list is empty it will return an empty string.

`string(//span[@class="output"]//a[starts-with(@href, "mailto:")])`